# Laravel 5.4 many delete method on one page

Tags: php, laravel

I have on the site / projects a list of user projects, for each button there is an icon that allows you to delete it. This works normally, but I have a list of users assigned to a given project and a button next to each user to be able to remove it from this project. I have a problem because I do not know how to delete a single user assigned to the project? Here is my code:

```
{!! Form::open([method'=>'DELETE', 'action' => ['ProjectsController@deleteUserFromProject', $project->id, $user->user_id]]) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Remove from project') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

web.php:

```
 Route::delete('/projects', 'ProjectsController@deleteUserFromProject');
```

controller:

```
 public function deleteUserFromProject($projectID, $userID)
{
}
```

Comment: `[method'=>'DELETE',` is a syntax error, missing first `'` (might just be a copy-paste issue)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a many to many relationship? You can use `detach` to remove a user from a project: `$product->users()->detach($userId);`

You can also provide the model to the controller to make it easier:

```
 public function deleteUserFromProject(Project $project, $userID)
 {
      $product->users()->detach($userId);
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is many to many relations. My problem is when i click 'remove from project' it's remove my project, not just user from this project..

Comment: Detach will not remove the project. You must have other code that is being run that deletes the project that you have not posted in your question.